# ws does not work in the browser. Browser clients must use the native WebSocket object

Tags: websocket, jestjs, puppeteer, chromium, jsdom

Node JS application giving a websocket error in a JEST, Puppeteer test. Chromium opens for a second and then closes instantly. I am not using websocket in my test so not sure why the attached error is happening.

Code to launch the webpage:

```js
beforeEach( async() => 
  {
    browser = await launch({ headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox','--disable-dev-shm-usage']});

    page = await browser.newPage();

    page.setViewport({ width: 1000, height: 750 });

    await page.goto(app);    

    await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0',});   });
```

[Screen of the error "Browser clients must use the native WebSocket object"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0GKT.png)

Verified that all the dev dependencies are in place:

- jest
- jest-puppeteer
- puppeteer
- chromium
- chromium-installer
- jest-image-snapshot
- jest-environment-jsdom

I am expecting to launch chromium and simulate actions on the web elements on a webpage.
How can I fix this error where Chromium opens and shuts immediately?

Comment: Probably not the problem, but don't forget to `await page.setViewport({ width: 1000, height: 750 });`

Comment: If you can create a [mcve] and provide your package.json, this might be worth opening up on Puppeteer's issues page since I don't see the error there yet. It could be something to do with jsdom confusing node into thinking it's a browser?

Comment: yes @ggorlen, you're right! Thats the problem. JSDOM is conflicting with the puppeteer environment.
If I comment our jsdom in jest.config.js then the chromium tests work fine. But I will still need JSDOM for other unit tests maybe. How can I configure both, depending on which test is being executed?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with JSDOM setup offhand, but maybe it's possible to not set JSDOM on the global config and import/set up `window` on a test by test or file by file basis. It's a good question with a clear error message and I'd suggest preserving that, but also maybe refining it or asking another question that's more specific about how to run JSDOM and jest-Puppeteer together in the same test environment, assuming you can't find any other resources (I didn't see much on a quick search). Or perhaps keep them in totally separate configs, since they're sort of different testing paradigms.

Comment: Also if you can share your config files, package.json and a full but minimal test suite it'd be easier to sit down and play with. Without that stuff it'd be a lot of work to set up an environment just to reproduce your original problem, never mind messing with it to make progress on the new problem. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all the help here, @ggorlen.

I stopped setting jsdom in the jest.config.js and added it in the script command in package.json:     "test:unit": "cd package && ./node_modules/.bin/jest --env=jsdom",

Comment: No problem. If you worked it out, could you add a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to help document everything necessary to get things working for future visitors with the same problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

1. Remove the testEnvironment from the jest.config.js:
   [Comment out in jest.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPhvL.png)
2. Add the environment as a param in the script command in package.json:
   [Shows scripts in package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mc8qq.png)

This way jsdom was not used in a global level and did not override Puppeteer everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use the [jest-puppeteer preset](https://jestjs.io/docs/puppeteer), which is a lot easier!